# Macbook froze, I turned it off, now login fails with "MacOS cannot be installed on your computer"

Tags: error

I was watching a video when my macbook pro froze.  Finally I held down the power button until it turned off, then turned it back on again.  After boot, I get an apple + loading bar for awhile, then I'm prompted for my password.  After entering the password I get the error in the title, along with: "An error occured while loading the installer resources".

What happened here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: do you have more than one user to log in ?

Comment: It seems there was auto update process but it is not sure. You should provide more information.

Comment: @Ruskes - yes, one non-admin and one admin login.  Both had the same issue.

Comment: @z0nam - I didn't notice any update message, but I agree with you.  What other info can I provide to help?

Comment: I found a solution similar to your case. https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/solved-macos-could-not-be-installed.256190/

Comment: @z0nam - I can't log in to type commands, however

Comment: Did you try safe booting or recovery mode?

Comment: @z0nam - I can log in with safe mode, but updates in settings show no pending / installable updates.  I reboot from safe mode and get the login menu, followed by a long loading bar, then the screen flickers and I get an apple logo (on a black background), then the error above again.

Comment: Did you try Restore or Internet Restore ? But first try Verbose mode (Command V) to see where it stops

Comment: Do you have any space left on your hard drive?